# How is data loaded from a remote database stored locally (in memory)

Tags: ios, database, storage, local

What is the best way that data loaded from a remote database can be stored locally on iOS. (You don't need to provide any code, I just want want to know the best way conceptually.)

For instance, take Twitter for iOS as an example. When it loads the tweets, does it just pull the tweet data from the remote database and store them in a local database on the iPhone? Or would it be better if the data is just stored locally as an array of objects or something similar?

See, I'm figuring that to be able to use/display the data from the remote database (for instance, in a dynamic table view), the data would have to be stored as objects anyway so maybe they should just be stored as objects in an array. However, when researching this, I did see a lot of articles about local databases, so I was thinking maybe its more efficient to load the remote data as a table and store it in a local database and use data directly from the local table to display the data or something similar.

Which one would require more overhead: storing the data as an array of Tweet objects or as a local database of tweets?

What do you think would be the best way of storing remote data locally (in memory) (for an app that loads data similar to how Twitter for iOS)?

I suppose this begs this prerequisite question: when data from a remote database is downloaded, is it usually loaded as a database table (result set) and therefore stored as one?

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at Restkit, I have used it quite extensively for this sort of thing.

Comment: I have found it equally as easy in the past to just grab the data from a web service, such as twitter, store it in an array or dictionary, and just use that however necessary. This will only require one network call when you want to update, and after that everything is there and ready to use however you feel necessary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it's very easy the put the fetched data right into your array and use it from there, it is likely that you would be benefitted by using a local database for two main reasons: scalability and persistance.

If you are hoping to download and display a large amount of data, it may be unsafe to try to store it in memory all at once. It would be more scalable to download whatever data you need, store it in a local database, and then fetch only the relevant objects you need to display.

If you download the data and only store it in an array, that data will have to be re-fetched from the remote database and re-parsed on next load of your app/view controller/etc before anything can be displayed. Instead, create a local database in which to store the downloaded data, allowing it to be readily available to display on next load while new data is fetched from your remote source.

While there is some initial overhead incurred in creating your database, the scalability and persistance that provides you is more than enough to warrant that. Storing the state of a remote database in a local database is an extremely common practice.

However, if you do not mind the user having to wait for this data to be fetched on every load, or the amount of data being fetched is relatively low or the data is incredibly simple, you will save time and effort on skipping the local database.